I have 101 reputation and I cannot answer a protected question
I would like to provide another answer in this question:
Number two in chinese: 二 vs 两
Due to to the fact that the given answers have not mentioned the etymology of the word at all.
The question is protected by user3306356 Dec 3 '14 at 9:16:

Because it has attracted low-quality answers, posting an answer now requires 10 reputation on this site.

I have currently 101 reputation, so why can't I answer this question?


Because it has attracted low-quality answers, posting an answer now requires 10 reputation on this site.

Your 101 comes from the default 1 rep + 100 rep association bonus.
None of these were earned on the site. So you never earned 10 reputation on the site, therefore were blocked from answering. 
This is a measure put in place so protected questions do not get "drive-by" answers by users who are not active on the site.

Yes, I thought of that, but then it should say "for posting an answer you need to earn at least 10 reputation on this site". Btw, I can answer to that question now.
